# Loading GDT from Late Bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, nasm, bootloader

I have an OS I'm working on currently and making a 2-stage bootloader called **early bootloader** (*DfltBoot*) and **late bootloader** (*AdvBoot*) and the early one does it's job and loads the late one and jumps to it's entry then starts executing code from there. Now that the late bootloader has been loaded, I want to switch into 32-bit Protected Mode (and 64-bit later but that's not important for now) and here's some of the code from both early and late bootloader. I won't put most of early bootloader's code, because it just does FAT12 loading stuff and loads the late bootloader into memory then starts executing it however I'm still gonna put the jump part to the late bootloader.

**DfltBoot.asm** *(Early Bootloader/Boot Sector)*

```
.ReadFinish: ; Gets jumped to whenever ADVBOOT.BIN get's loaded into memory
    mov [EBR_DriveNumber], dl ; Save the boot drive

    ; Set the segments again
    mov ax, ADVBOOT_LoadSegment
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    jmp ADVBOOT_LoadSegment:ADVBOOT_LoadOffset ; Segment = 0x2000 Offset=0x0
    jmp WaitKeyAndReboot ; Shouldn't get executed, late bootloader won't return.
```

The above code of the early bootloader works just fine, the late bootloader does get jumped to, because I'm still in 16-bit Real Mode I can print chars so I did those in the late bootloader and it does print the character, so the reading and the jumping part in the early bootloader should be working just fine.

The problems arise within some late code in the late bootloader tho, here is the full code of the late bootloader:

**AdvBoot.asm** *(Late Bootloader/The actual bootloader)*

```
org 0x0
bits 16

Start:
    cli
    lgdt [GDT_Descriptor]

    ; Set the 32-bit flag in control register 0
    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    ;;; Problematic part
    jmp GDT_CodeSegment:ProtectedModeStart ; Far jump to flush the pipeline

bits 32

ProtectedModeStart:
    ; NOTE: This label doesn't get jumped to, I tried putting a jmp $ here
    ; and QEMU just crashed on me. If I put it before the far jump, it does
    ; actually stop and not crash, so I'd assume the far jump is the problem.
    mov ax, GDT_DataSegment
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    mov edx, 0xb8000
    mov ah, 0x0f
    mov al, 'B'
    mov [edx], ax
    jmp $
    
    %include "Boot/GDT.asm"
```

As said by the comments as well, the far jump part, when executed crashes the entire computer and restarts and the cycle repeats. I'm not sure if it's relevant in this case but in case it is here's my GDT:

**GDT.asm**

```
GDT_Start:

GDT_Null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0

GDT_Code:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0

GDT_Data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0

GDT_End:

GDT_Descriptor:
    dw GDT_End - GDT_Start - 1
    dd GDT_Start

GDT_CodeSegment equ GDT_Code - GDT_Start
GDT_DataSegment equ GDT_Data - GDT_Start
```

I don't get what the problem is even about, is it segments, GDT or something else.

Comment: `jmp GDT_CodeSegment:ProtectedModeStart` is wrong since `ProtectedModeStart` is not the correct offset. Something like `jmp GDT_CodeSegment:ProtectedModeStart+ADVBOOT_LoadSegment*16` might work. Similarly your `dd GDT_Start` is wrong as well.

Comment: @Jester I changed to jump instruction but how do I even offset a label? It's still crashing.

Comment: But then `ds` also needs to be loaded with `0`.

Comment: It still crashes, I changed `org` to `0x2000 * 16` and jmp to `GDT_CodeSegment::ProtectedModeStart+0x2000*16`

Comment: I set ax to zero then ds to ax, still crashing.

Comment: I've changed jump back to `GDT_CodeSegment:ProtectedModeStart` again but it still crashes, jump still fails.

Comment: I cannot because the early bootloader is limited to 512 bytes in size and it is nearly full because it makes a lot of disk utility and there's no space left, a few bytes remain but they are not even enough to contain the GDT structure itself, let alone the instructions to load it

Comment: The quick fix didn't work too, still crashing (Also assembler warning: Byte and word data exceeds bounds)

Comment: You should make sure 1) `lgdt [GDT_Descriptor]` is using the proper real mode offset relative to whatever you have in `ds` 2) `jmp GDT_CodeSegment:ProtectedModeStart` is using the proper protected mode offset relative to your new `CS` base (zero) and 3) `dd GDT_Start` is using a linear address.

Comment: About `ds`, didn't we just set that to `0`? Also GDT is a packed structure included at once into the main bootloader assembly, and I don't know about that `cs` offsetting.

Comment: It's unclear what you changed to what so I just re-stated the 3 parts that need to be in sync. Do whatever is needed. Note that loading to segment `2000` will not make it possible to set `ds` to zero since then the offset will be out of range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three crucial parts that need to use the proper addresses.

1. The `lgdt [GDT_Descriptor]`. Since you load `ds` with `ADVBOOT_LoadSegment` and you have `org 0x0` this is actually fine.
2. The `jmp GDT_CodeSegment:ProtectedModeStart`. This needs an offset relative to the protected mode segment base which is zero. Thus you need to adjust it by the load segment such as `jmp dword GDT_CodeSegment:ADVBOOT_LoadSegment*16+ProtectedModeStart`. Note you need the `dword` because the offset does not fit in 16 bits. You could also set the base address of the segment but that is not recommended.
3. The `dd GDT_Start`. This needs to be a linear address. Similarly to the previous point, you should adjust it like `dd GDT_Start+ADVBOOT_LoadSegment*16`

All of these assume `ADVBOOT_LoadOffset` is zero. With these changes your code seems to be working (after I filled in the missing pieces since you did not provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! I changed the calculations in the GDT_Descriptor and changed the far jump, I get my 'B' printed at the top of the screen! I'll be on my hunt for long mode now then.

Comment: Hey, I have a quick question, would I need this sort of `jmp` instruction when far jumping to a 64-bit label?

Comment: Yes, and make sure destination is in 32 bit range.

Comment: Does that mean I would replace 0x2000 with 0x200000 or something else?

Comment: Wherever your code is.

Comment: Well I have `jmp dword GDT64_CodeSegment+0x2000*16:LongModeEntry` (changed 0x2000 to 0x200000 for testing) and I crash, I offset the GDT64_Descriptor by 0x2000*16, I think this should stay same because it's label offsetting

Comment: You did the addition in the wrong place. You want to add to the offset not the segment. `jmp dword GDT64_CodeSegment:0x2000*16+LongModeEntry`

Comment: Ohh yes I don't know what I even was thinking there, but I still crash, what's it with far jumps and me